# Kotlin: initializing vals within custom builder function

Tags: kotlin, scope, initialization, builder, val

I created some custom data types and corresponding builders which are heavily used within unit tests. The general pattern looks somewhat like this:

```kotlin
@Test
fun testSomething(){
  object {
    val someVal: SomeType
    val someOtherVal: SomeOtherType
    init {
      // everything is a `val`, properly declared and type safe
      with(Builder()){
        someVal = type(/*args*/).apply {
          someOtherVal = otherType(/*other args*/)
        }
      }
    }
  }.run {
    // Run Code and do Assertions...
    // notice how I can use `someVal` and `someOtherVal` directly (woohoo scopes)
  }
}
```

the corresponding types and builders:

```kotlin
class SomeType()
class SomeOtherType(parent: SomeType)
class Builder(){
  fun type() = SomeType()
  fun SomeType.otherType() = SomeOtherType(parent = this)
}
```

I then realized that i'm to lazy to always call `apply` on the parent type and instead wanted to move the call to `apply` into the builder. Looking into its [definition](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) I did realize I will need the `inline` keyword:

```kotlin
// within the Builder: redefine function `type`
inline fun type(block: SomeType.()->Unit = {}) = SomeType().apply(block)
```

and within the unit test:

```kotlin
// within the init:
with(Builder()){
  someVal = type(/*args*/) {
    // I saved the `apply` call and thus  6 characters, time to get some ice cream
    someOtherVal = otherType(/*other args*/)
  }
}
```

But now IntelliJ marks `someOtherVal` and gives as error

> [CAPTURED_MEMBER_VAL_INITIALIZATION] Captured member values initialization is forbidden due to possible reassignment

Which is understandable but this would also mean that it would be impossible for the `apply` function in the first example. One could argue that the compiler *knows* whats happening as `apply` is part of the standard library. But it is *just* a library, not a language feature.

Can I get rid of the error and fix my own builder or do I have to stick with manually calling `apply`?

Btw.: Defining the variables as `lateinit` or `var` is not a solution.

Comment: The compiler knows about the code in `apply` definitely being called exactly one time because of something called Kotlin contracts. You can look that up to see how it works.

Comment: I don’t see what the `object { }.run { }` construct is buying you. Just looks like an extra layer of complexity and there would be no behavioral change if that was completely removed.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to assign to `val`s in a `with` block because `with` is guaranteed to call the lambda you gave it *exactly once*, and immediately.

The compiler doesn't know that your `type` method also calls the lambda exactly once, and immediately. As far as the compiler is concerned, the lambda could very possibly be called more than once, escape to somewhere else, or whatever. And if that is the case, that would mean `someOtherVal` is assigned multiple times, and this cannot happen because it is a `val`.

You can do what `with` does, and use the experimental contracts API:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalContracts::class)
inline fun type(block: SomeType.()->Unit = {}): SomeType {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    return SomeType().apply(block)
}
```

Since this seems to be a temporary object just for testing, I'd rather just make `someOtherVal` a `lateinit var` instead. Or change the design of the `Builder` completely. The `Builder` should return just *one* thing, and you can assign the properties of that built thing to your `val`s instead.